# Java java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException and IO Can't write to file

Tags: java, windows, selenium, io, openjdk-11

I have tried three different projects and tested them but none of them is working..

- While trying to write to a file I get "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException";

```
List<String> contents = Arrays.asList("Hey, there!", "What's up?");
Files.write(Paths.get("C://Users//*****//Documents//NetBeansProjects//SelTest‪//output.txt"), contents);
```

Java output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\*****\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SelTest‪\output.txt
```

I have that output.txt file created and ready.

One more error, While trying to save an image from a BufferedImage, My code was executed successfully but nothing was created?

```
ImageIO.write(outputImage, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\****\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SelTest‪\\love.jpg"));
```

I can display the BufferedImage as a label and it is rendered fine but ImageIO.write, show no error code successfully executed but no file created!

The last thing I tried today, was reading Selenium driver. I have set the driver path well and it is in right place but still doesn't get the driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Users\\*****\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SelTest‪\\msedgedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

JavaOutput

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\*****\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SelTest‪\msedgedriver.exe
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
```

I'm using Apache NetBeans IDE 12 and my Java:

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. your absolute path slash must be back slash.
2. if render image is empty or null then nothing will be happend
   `Parameter im: @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`

Comment: On Windows either slash is fine as `Path.of("C:/")` is same as `Path.of("C:\\")`

Comment: then he's passing a different/non-existing path

Comment: Hello Abdul, 

I forgot to mention that either in both ways, back slash or not is fine.. it still same...

About the image, it is not image I could make a label and add it on the label as an ICON from the same BufferedImage value. so it is not empty.

Comment: okay then check your security permissions of working directory. maybe write permission not allowed.

Comment: IF you mean on Windows.. it is all allowed and working fine but not sure what is really wrong!

Comment: I had also face this issue on the client side. where the programs files folder have only read access.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on one question at a time. The `Files.write` method does not create folder structure for you so gives `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException` when the a directory path does not exist.

You can add a step to create the path to the parent folder for the ImageIO and text file example like this:

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:/Users/*****/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SelTest‪/output.txt");
Files.createDirectories(p.getParent())
Files.write(p, contents);
```

You do not need to use double slash `//` in paths on Windows.

Comment: Thank you DuncG, My problem is not that... Using // or \ or / doesn't make any difference. 

The directory exists and I even created the output.txt file myself manually to see if that will help. it doesn't even help even, it still shows the same error 

I feel there is something related with either permission or Java on windows